# Printing Messages after Every 10 second elapsed in a for loop

Tags: python

Any way to print message every 10 second until 100 time sleep has been completed while a for loop is running with time.sleep

Comment: Consider rewriting your question. It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need

```
import time

for i in range(99, 0, -1):
    time.sleep(1)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('hello')    # Print every 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
i=100
while i>0:
    time.sleep(10)  #this will make 10 second of gap after every print
    print(i)
    i-=1
```